# Finding Duplicate (Key, Value) in Map

Tags: scala

I wrote a function for checking if a `Map[(String, String)]` contains an element with a matching key and value:

```
  def findDupes(map: Map[String, String], key: String, value: String): 
                           Option[(String, String)] = {
    val dupes = map.collect { case (x, y) if(x == key && y == value) => key }
    dupes match {
      case Nil     => None
      case x :: _  => Some(key, value)
    }
  }
```

**Testing**

```
scala> map
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> HELLO, 2 -> WORLD)

scala> findDupes(map, "1", "HELLO")
res8: Option[(String, String)] = Some((1,HELLO))

scala> findDupes(map, "1", "FOO")
res9: Option[(String, String)] = None
```

Comment: Is it just me or I don't see the definition of the values of `map` in your example of use?

Comment: just added with `map`'s definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map get key contains value`, to test if a given key-value-pair is already part of a `Map`.

Your solution is extremely inefficient, because you iterate through the entire `Map` (with `collect`) just to find one value. `get` returns an `Option` which can be checked for the containing value.

Answer (score 0):

`collectFirst` will not necessarily iterate through the whole collection and will also return an Option so you don't have to do the pattern match:

```
def findDupes(map: Map[String, String], key: String, value: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
    map.collectFirst( {case (`key`,`value`) => (key,value)})
  }
```